# Why is this type annotation failing?

Tags: clojure

I would like to understand why I cannot add a return type annotation to this dot product function in clojure.

```
(defn dot3
  "3d vector dot product"
  ^double [^doubles [u0 u1 u2]
           ^doubles [v0 v1 v2]]
  (+ (* u0 v0) (* u1 v1) (* u2 v2)))
```

In the log below you can see that an annotation for a subtract works just fine and if I remove the `^double` return type annotation it also works.  But, the above code produces an error when called:

```
user=> (dot3 [4 5 6] [1 2 3])    
ClassCastException user$dot3 cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn$OOD  user/eval3487 (form-init8441686871120943013.clj:1)
```

Thanks in advance,

--Roger

```
thunder 13:17:21 clojure> lein version
Leiningen 2.5.0 on Java 1.8.0_25 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
thunder 13:17:28 clojure> lein new test123
Generating a project called test123 based on the 'default' template.
The default template is intended for library projects, not applications.
To see other templates (app, plugin, etc), try `lein help new`.
thunder 13:18:09 clojure> cd test123
thunder 13:18:14 test123> lein repl
nREPL server started on port 57240 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:57240
REPL-y 0.3.5, nREPL 0.2.6
Clojure 1.6.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_25-b17
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e

user=> (defn vsub3
  #_=>   "3d vector subtraction"
  #_=>   ^doubles [^doubles [u0 u1 u2]
  #_=>             ^doubles [v0 v1 v2]]
  #_=>   [(- u0 v0) (- u1 v1) (- u2 v2)])
#'user/vsub3
user=> (vsub3 [4 5 6] [1 2 3])
[3 3 3]
user=> (defn dot3
  #_=>   "3d vector dot product"
  #_=>   ^double [^doubles [u0 u1 u2]
  #_=>            ^doubles [v0 v1 v2]]
  #_=>   (+ (* u0 v0) (* u1 v1) (* u2 v2)))
#'user/dot3
user=> (dot3 [4 5 6] [1 2 3])
ClassCastException user$dot3 cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn$OOD  user/eval3487 (form-init8441686871120943013.clj:1)
user=> (defn dot3
  #_=>   "3d vector dot product"
  #_=>   [^doubles [u0 u1 u2]
  #_=>    ^doubles [v0 v1 v2]]
  #_=>   (+ (* u0 v0) (* u1 v1) (* u2 v2)))
#'user/dot3
user=> (dot3 [4 5 6] [1 2 3])
32
```

Comment: FYI when you provide an incorrect annotation, the reflection warning on compilation will go away, but you still pay the CPU cost for runtime reflection because the types were wrong. For an annotation of `^doubles` the argument should be of type `"[D;"` (primitive array of double), not a PersistentVector of Long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type annotation you have provided is incompatible with the way you specify your arguments to the function.

Destructuring is preventing the proper code from being compiled. It turns out that this is a bug in current Clojure versions, but will be fixed with the 1.7 release.

The following version works properly:

```
(defn dot3
  "3d vector dot product"
  ^double [^doubles u
           ^doubles v]
   (+ (* (aget u 0) (aget v 0))
      (* (aget u 1) (aget v 1))
      (* (aget u 2) (aget v 2))))

user=> (dot3 (double-array [4.0 5.0 6.0]) (double-array [1.0 2.0 3.0]))
32.0
```

Comment: Thank you.  This cleared it up for me.  But I don't know how I would've figured this out from the compile error...   I would like it to fail (or warn) if I do something bone-headed like use a PersistentVector instead of primitive array...

Comment: There is a primitive-math lib that helps [ztellman/primative-math](https://github.com/ztellman/primitive-math) -- and yeah, Clojure error / compilation messages are often tricky to decipher.

Comment: Follow up: it looks like this is actually a bug you found, that is fixed in 1.7 https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/85169b785c5dd59e89c0bd12600eebe5f6172874

Comment: Does this bugfix mean that (dot3 [4.0 5.0 6.0] [1.0 2.0 3.0]) would as well as (dot3 (double-array [4.0 5.0 6.0]) (double-array [1.0 2.0 3.0])) in 1.7?

Comment: it would mean that the definition of dot3 using destructuring would work, calling it with anything other than `(double-array ...)` args would still pay the penalty for reflection

Comment: Use `aget`, not `get`, to look things up in a primitive array, else the typehints are wasted.

Comment: I changed the answer's get -> aget per amalloy.  Indeed, I did have to change to use aget to achieve the hoped-for speed.